# Extracting elements from a tex file

Tags: extract

I would like to extract the contents of various latex commands, e.g.

- section
- chapter
- caption
- sidenote, etc

from a `.tex` file. These elements would eventually end up in a CSV file

```
chapter, chapter 1 title text
chapter, chapter 2 title text
figure, figure text
```

Does this require a regular expression or is this reinventing the wheel?

---

The `.tex` file is generated from a markdown document, via pandoc.

---

### Example A

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\Quux{Pouet}

\begin{document}
\chapter[foo]{Foo}
\url{http://www.tex.org}
\end{document}
```

I would like to extract the chapters and urls.

### Example B

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chap}
\marginnote{A note}
\end{document}
```

I would like to extract the marginnote

Comment: One way would be to modify those commands so that they also generate the desired CSV file that you require. However, it would be useful to know what the ultimate goal with the CSV file is as there may already be hooks to achieve the final goal.

Comment: if you don't have nested braces/brackets then a `regex` should be fairly straight forward. if you do have nested braces/brackets, then some care will be needed. for example `\chapter{my chapter \emph{text} goes here}`

Comment: I intend to parse the csv file with r/python to ensure style guidelines are met. E.g. title case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a file like this to instrument all sectioning commands (let's call it `instrumenter.tex`):

```latex
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \l_csgillespie_iow

% #1: sectioning command name as a single token
% #2: character tokens representing the command name, without the backslash
\cs_new_protected:Npn \csgillespie_instrument_sec_cmd:Nn #1#2
  {
    % Save the original sectioning command
    \cs_gset_eq:cN { g_csgillespie_#2_orig: } #1

    \RenewDocumentCommand #1 { s O{##3} m }
      {
        \iow_now:Nn \l_csgillespie_iow { #2 ; ##2 ; ##3 }

        \IfBooleanTF {##1}
          { \use:c { g_csgillespie_#2_orig: } * {##3} }
          { \use:c { g_csgillespie_#2_orig: } [##2] {##3} }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \csgillespie_instrument_sec_cmd:Nn { c }

% #1: character tokens representing the command name, without the backslash
\cs_new_protected:Npn \csgillespie_instrument_sec_cmd_ifexists:n #1
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cT {#1}
      { \csgillespie_instrument_sec_cmd:cn {#1} {#1} }
  }

\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \iow_open:Nn \l_csgillespie_iow { sectioning.csv }
    \clist_map_inline:nn
      {
        part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph,
        subparagraph
      }
      { \csgillespie_instrument_sec_cmd_ifexists:n {#1} }
  }

\AtEndDocument { \iow_close:N \l_csgillespie_iow }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\endinput
```

Then, suppose that you want to check a file called `tested.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand*\Quux{Pouet}

\begin{document}

  \chapter[foo]{Foo}
  \chapter{Bar \emph{Baz!}}
  \chapter*{\Quux !}
  \section{A \emph{section}!}
  \section[Short title]{Another section}

\end{document}
```

All you have to do is to put `instrumenter.tex` in a location present in `TEXINPUTS` (possibly the same directory as `tested.tex`), then run:

```
latex '\input instrumenter \input tested'
```

(single-quotes are for the shell here, adapt to your shell). You'll obtain a file called `sectioning.csv` in the same directory as `tested.tex` that looks like this for this example:

```
chapter;foo;Foo
chapter;Bar \emph {Baz!};Bar \emph {Baz!}
chapter;\Quux !;\Quux !
section;A \emph {section}!;A \emph {section}!
section;Short title;Another section
```

You may want to add double quotes to the output (or whatever you need for the CSV format) in case some titles contain the semi-colon separator (`;`). Just add them in the line that reads:

```latex
\iow_now:Nn \l_csgillespie_iow { #2 ; ##2 ; ##3 }
```

## Paragraphs in arguments

In case you use this code to wrap other commands and these commands can legally have `\par` tokens (e.g., blank lines) in their arguments, then add a `+` in front of the corresponding arguments, like this:

```latex
\RenewDocumentCommand #1 { s +O{##3} +m }
```

The `O{##3}` corresponds to the optional argument of the wrapped command (defaulting to the value of the mandatory argument), the `m` to its mandatory argument. The `+` shouldn't be useful for standard sectioning commands, but might be if you use this system to log arguments of other commands.

Comment: The example from your previous comment works fine for me, I get: `chapter;A chap;A chap`. Regarding your first comment, please submit a minimal working example. My code relies on the standard LaTeX syntax for the sectioning commands. Of course, if you happen to use a class that redefines these commands to have a non-standard syntax, the code will not work without adaptations to the actually-used syntax. I don't know if this is the case here (no experience with `tufte`, and a quick look at `texdoc tufte-latex` didn't tell me anything interesting regarding this)—just thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: (My file is called `instrumenter.tex`.) I'm afraid both of your examples work fine here. The `sectioning.csv` file obtained from example A contains one line (`chapter;foo;Foo`) and the one obtained from example B also contains one line, which is `chapter;A chap;A chap`. It's all as expected. What kind of errors do you obtain? It is very, very strange that `\url` could cause an error, because my code doesn't modify it in any way. Did you test the examples *as is*, in an otherwise empty directory?

Comment: Note that you can use `instrumenter.tex` from a parent dir, as in `pdflatex '\input ../instrumenter \input example-A'` or `latex '\input ../instrumenter \input example-B'` (I run the first command from a folder containing only `example-A.tex` and the second one from a folder containing only `example-B.tex`). The slash separators work on Linux (TL 2019), at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97528/discussion-between-csgillespie-and-frougon).

Answer (score 3):

The extract package would allow you to do that:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract

The documentation in the readme there (extract.pdf) is quite good.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that out.